# AWS Athena ODI JDBC connection

Tags: amazon-athena

Has anyone tried connecting AWS Athena from Oracle Data Integrator.

I have been trying this since long but am not able to find the appropriate JDBC connection string.

Steps I have followed from 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html#jdbc-url-format

1. Downloaded AthenaJDBC42_2.0.7.jar driver from AWS
2. Copied the same into the userlib directory of ODI
3. Created new technology in ODI
4. Trying to add Data server. Not able to form JDBC url.

JDBC string Sample format (which isn't working):

```
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=[Region];User=[AccessKey];Password=[SecretKey];S3OutputLocation=[Output];
```

Please can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I missed to post answer on this.
It all worked fine after configuring a Athena JDBC connection in ODI like below and providing the 4 key values while connecting.

JDBC URL: jdbc:awsathena://athena.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:443;AWSCredentialsProviderArguments=ACCESSKEYID,SECRETACCESSKEY,SESSIONTOKEN

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is sorter version of `JDBC` I implemented for Athena. This was just `POC` and we want to go with `AWS SDK` rather then `jdbc` though less important here.

```
package com.poc.aws.athena;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class AthenaJDBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        Class.forName("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;User=EXAMPLEKEY;"
                + "Password=EXAMPLESECRETKYE;S3OutputLocation=s3://example-bucket-name-us-east-1;");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet queryResults = statement.executeQuery(ExampleConstants.ATHENA_SAMPLE_QUERY);
        System.out.println(queryResults.next());

    }
}
```

The only important point here related to `url`.

`jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;User=EXAMPLEKEY;"
                    + "Password=EXAMPLESECRETKYE;S3OutputLocation=s3://example-bucket-name-us-east-1;`.

1. `us-east-1` must be replaced with your actual region like `us-west-1` etc
2. `EXAMPLEKEY` must be replaced with your `AWS Access key` that has Athena access.
3. `EXAMPLESECRETKEY` must be replaced with your `AWS Secret key` that has Athena access.
4. `example-bucket-name-us-east-1` must be replaced with your `S3 bucket` that above `keys` has write access too.

There other keys simba driver support but less important here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Anksy77, did you try the code I have provided and does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually we have been trying to connect to Athena from Oracle Data Integrator specifically. Reason is we need to join the cloud data from S3 with the on-prem Oracle data systems(for which the ODI is already being used). Any help with the ODI JDBC connection string would be highly appreciated. Sample string which isn't getting through : jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=athena.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:443;User=XXXX;Password=XXXXX;S3OutputLocation=s3://athena-poc;

Comment: @Anksy77, this url works too, not sure if you are missing something in your question or steps. `jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443;User=EXAMPLEKEY;Password=EXAMPLESECRETKEY;S3OutputLocation=s3://example-bucket-name-us-east-1;`

Comment: Thanks Red Boy. I tried with the format that you have mentioned above. Unfortunately it is giving me login timeout in ODI. Although with same secretkey it allows me to connect on AWSCLI and list the S3 contents.

Comment: It might be ODI issue, but I recommend you to try just main program and see if it work. This will confirm you if issue is with ODI only.

Comment: yes that's the next thing I am trying to do. Will let you know if it works. Thanks!